# How to solve this :Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Max Robinson\anaconda3\python.exe?

Tags: anaconda3

PS C:\Users\Max Robinson\Anaconda3\Scripts> activate

C:\Users\Max Robinson\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda.bat activate
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Max Robinson\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Max Robinson\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe activate '

PS C:\Users\Max Robinson\Anaconda3\Scripts> activate